# What is the rated output current in different MOTs?

Tags: transformer, amperage, microwave

I've been looking at LG service manuals, searching parts numbers, and the lot; but I can't seem to find anything concrete. I see websites throwing around "generally 1 amp" a lot and other sources saying 0.5 amps. Located in the U.S. (where wall outlets supply 120V AC), I assume that the value will be about half an amp for ovens rated at 1000 W or so since I've measured each of my transformers outputs to be within 2000-2300V. Does anyone have any information?

*p.s. please don't lecture me about MOTs saying that I'm going to die, I've been working with them for over a decade and know how to be relatively safe around them.*

Comment: What does the data sheet say?

Comment: The service manual gives a replacement part number, but no information on the transformer itself @Andyaka

Comment: Electrical engineers design using components with data sheets because it's paramount to any system of quality control and providing reliability to the customer. How do you ensure this without data sheets? Surely the supplier of the parts is obliged to provide decent technical information on the parts so you can use them in your application correctly?

Comment: @Andyaka which is exactly why trying to find this information is frustrating. I threw a couple part numbers into Datasheet Archive with no luck. I can try reaching out to the manufacturer of the part, but I’m afraid of a paywall between me and the data like LG has with its service manuals.

Comment: Why don't you design your own transformer then? That puts you in charge of things.

Comment: That’s just a paywall with extra steps ;) @Andyaka

Comment: If reliability *isn't* paramount, then the rating is "as high as you can go before it overheats". I *think* microwave transformers are made with magnetic shunts which prevents them from overloading, even at short-circuit.

Comment: @user253751 you are correct about the shunts. Rather than “as high as you can go before it overheats” I was looking for “as high as the manufacturer says is healthy for the poor thing”

Comment: When you use salvaged parts you often just don't have the numbers. If you can figure out who originally made the transformer (not the microwave) you may be able to look it up. You could also measure the temperature at different amounts of current and choose a cutoff point. The manufacturer's design intent is just their intent - characterizing the part yourself, in a way the manufacturer didn't, *is* valid (although usually you don't need to do characterizations the manufacturer already did and you lost the documents for)

Comment: Microwave oven transformers are designed for the particular job, with rather nasty characteristics dictated by extreme cost reduction (no-load losses are in the 100W range and they require forced air cooling to keep from burning up in operation). I doubt you will find a datasheet comparable to the datasheet of, say, a Hammond transformer even from the official transformer manufacturers.

Comment: In addition, the load it's designed to drive is quite far from being a resistive load, so it has characteristics that benefit that (leakage inductance). They would have internal (shared only with vendors, if that) documents that define the characteristics, though not necessarily in terms you'd find particularly useful, more in practical terms to confirm proper manufacturing and testing of the component.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany **“no-load losses are in the 100W range”** yeah, I like the way they growl while doing nothing. **“They require forced air cooling to keep from burning up in operation”** the fan in a microwave is to cool the magnetron (it’s aimed into the heatsink fins), not the transformer. **”They have characteristics that benefit that (leakage inductance)”** yes, and I’m using that to my advantage. **“They would have internal documents”** I was afraid of that.

Comment: As **@SpehroPefhany** pointed out, MOT manufacturers would most likely not make the datasheet to an extremely dangerous and deadly part publicly available to consumers, as this would encourage self-service and/or tinkering from the inexperienced, which may very well lead to their electrocution. Additionally, as **@user253751** says, "characterizing the part yourself, in a way the manufacturer didn't, *is* valid." It just takes a bit of testing and monitoring to find reliable values.